# BTreeMap terminal display issue in Rust

Tags: rust, display, btreemap

I have a beautified string which I want to associate to a key and I want to display it from a Hashmap or a BTreeMap in Rust. My string is shown below as follows:-

```
The `beautified_string` which when printed on terminal using println!("{}", beautified_string) 
    
    {
      "a1": "nWM0MM",
      "b1": "YErSKv",
      "c1": "B",
      "d1": [
        "AIBAC",
        "AH8EA"
      ]
    }
```

However, when I associate this to a map like this

```
let m = BTreeMap::new()
m.insert("a", beautified_string)
```

When I do `println!("{:?}", m)` I get,

```
{"a": "{\n  \"a1\": \"nWM0MM\",\n  \"b1\": \"YErSKv\",\n  \"c1\": \"B\",\n  \"d1\": [\n    \"AIBAC\",\n    \"AH8EA\"\n  ]\n}"}
```

Is it possible to get an output like this from the map?

```
"a": {
  "a1": "nWM0MM",
  "b1": "YErSKv",
  "c1": "B",
  "d1": [
    "AIBAC",
    "AH8EA"
  ]
}
```

Comment: You need some deserialization/parsing stuff. This looks like JSON, so... https://docs.rs/serde-json.

Comment: `Debug` implementations are meant to be an easy way to have a glance at your data. If you need a secific formatting you should create a custom type with a `Display` imlplementation that suits your needs. A newtype struct would work in case you want custom output of an existing datatype.

Answer (score 0):

What I did here, was I converted a `BTreeMap` to a JSON string using `serde_json` library, and then I used the `from_str` function to parse a JSON string and convert it to a Rust value

```rust
use serde_json::{to_string, json, Value, from_str};
use std::collections::BTreeMap;


fn main() {
    let mut m = BTreeMap::new();

    let beautified_string = json!({
        "a": {
            "a1": "nWM0MM",
            "b1": "YErSKv",
            "c1": "B",
            "d1": [
                "AIBAC",
                "AH8EA"
            ]
        }
    });

    m.insert(0, beautified_string);

    let json = to_string(&m).unwrap();

    let data: Value = from_str(&json).unwrap();

    println!("{:#}", data);

}
```

link to Rust Playground = https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c9051c6c84618bab2299c17a824c59d4